# Python method for simulation similar to R

Tags: python, r, simulation, jobs, simpy

I have manufactoring problem that I want to simulate in python. There are different types of jobs and each jobs has a set amount of manufactoring orders.
For example it could be that you are manufacturing different types of vehicles, like a car with 4 wheels and motorcycle with 2 wheels. So the vehicle is the job, and the wheels are the manufacturing order. The jobs are beeing generatet at different times, splitet into the manufactoring orders and then go through a couple of processes. At the end all the parts of a job are assembled and then the job is finished.
Now in R there is a pretty simple method (clone and synchronize), but I was not able to find something similar in python. Any ideas? I would be happy with any suggestions.

Comment: So you'd like some sort of Python pipeline package?

Comment: Do  you know the probabilities of each event occurring?

Comment: The probability for each event is 100%. They just occur at different times, with different frequencies.